# Duplicate error after added -ObjC linker flag

Tags: ios, google-maps, compiler-errors, static-libraries, webrtc

I'm integrating [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios) in my existing [webrtc](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios) xcode project. It requires to add -ObjC linker flag, so i get a lot of duplicate error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARDAppClient in:
    /Users/phuongle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/AppRTCDemo.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppRTCDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ARDAppClient.o
        AppRTCDemo/WebRTC/libWebRTC-armv7.a(apprtc_signaling.ARDAppClient.o)
    ...
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARDAppEngineClient in:
    /Users/phuongle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/AppRTCDemo.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppRTCDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ARDAppEngineClient.o
        AppRTCDemo/WebRTC/libWebRTC-armv7.a(apprtc_signaling.ARDAppEngineClient.o)
    ...
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARDCEODTURNClient in:
    /Users/phuongle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/AppRTCDemo.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppRTCDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ARDCEODTURNClient.o
        AppRTCDemo/WebRTC/libWebRTC-armv7.a(apprtc_signaling.ARDCEODTURNClient.o)
    ...
duplicate symbol _SRWebSocketErrorDomain in:
    /Users/phuongle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/AppRTCDemo.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppRTCDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SRWebSocket.o
        AppRTCDemo/WebRTC/libWebRTC-armv7.a(socketrocket.SRWebSocket.o)
ld: 114 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can build without error if i remove -ObjC linker flag. Many thanks for your advice

Comment: In my case, the issue goes away after i update the latest Google Maps SDK.